# Grammar question: "had been"

Tags: grammar

"In March 2014, I led a team of students to campaign against the way in which a society election at my university had been conducted."

In this sentence structure with a date at the front, is it correct to use "had been" in this way?

Comment: What are the alternatives that you are considering? I don't see a reason why "had been" is incorrect, but knowing if there are other phrasings you are considering would help others answer the question.

Comment: It's correct if you mean "I led a team" is what happened in March 2014 and "had been conducted" happened at an earlier time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct either with or without the opening.

> I led a team of students to campaign against the way in which a society election at my university had been conducted.
>
> In March 2014, I led a team ... in which a society election ... had been conducted.
>
> During my 3rd year of studies, I led a team...

Those are all well-formed and comprehensible sentences.

Comment: *Those are all well-formed* Why  is that?